# Receving send json to server and recive json response

Tags: android, json, database

the problem is this, if I use the test values(in php file) the json is processed and the app receives the resulting json from the server, but when I use the json values  ​​from app i cant get the resulting json

(Java):

```
private class enviarcoord extends AsyncTask{

@Override


protected JSONArray doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

JSONObject Jobj =params[0];
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resposta;
String respostasv ="";
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

try{

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("MEU SITE ONLINE");
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(Jobj.toString(), "UTF8"));
resposta = httpclient.execute(post);

Log.i("Http Response:",resposta .toString());
String temp = EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity());
Log.i("tag", temp);

//bota tentar

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("MEU SITE ONLINE");
try {
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) {
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
builder.append(line);
}
} else {
Log.e(ParseException.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
}
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
respostasv = builder.toString();


// tratar a resposta

jsonArr = new JSONArray(respostasv);



}

catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.i("ClienteProt", "ClientProtocolException");

}

catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.i("IOE", "IOException");

} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
Log.i("IOE", "erro a criar o array json");
}

// se der erro o return vai devolver vazio
return jsonArr;
}
```

the server receives the json and do processing like this:

(PHP):

```
require_once "db/DB.php"; //connect to a database/disconnect handler.



$jobj = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

$earth_radius = 3960.00; # em milhas

$MlocLat_1 = $jobj->Latitude;
$MlocLon_1 = $jobj->Longitude;
$Distancia = $jobj->Distancia;

// VALORES DE TESTES
/*

$MlocLat_1 = "41.6529";
$MlocLon_1 = "-8.58453";
$Distancia =1;

*/


$conjcoord = 0;

$db = DB::getDB();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM coordenada";
$idterreno=0;

$result=$db->query($sql);


while($row=$result->fetch_object()){
$conjcoord++;

if(distance_haversine($MlocLat_1, $MlocLon_1, $row->Latitude, $row->Longitude) <= $Distancia*1000){


if($idterreno != $row->id_info){
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM informacao WHERE Id_informacao= $row->id_info ";
$result2=$db->query($sql2);


while($row2=$result2->fetch_object()){
$output[]=$row2;
}
$idterreno =$row->id_info;
}

}


}


//########### calculo distancia entre pontos gps
function distance_haversine($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
global $earth_radius;



$delta_lat = $lat2 - $lat1 ;
$delta_lon = $lon2 - $lon1 ;

$alpha = $delta_lat/2;
$beta = $delta_lon/2;
$a = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
$c = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
$distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
$distance = round($distance, 4);
$distance = $distance * 1.609344;
return $distance;
}


print (json_encode($output));


?>
```

Comment: What do you mean? The JSONData generated by the app cant be processed by the Webserver, right? Which errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

It may be already answered in [How to decode JSON values in my Android Aplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726008/how-to-decode-json-values-in-my-android-aplication/23726092#23726092)

BUT,

if you want to parse JSON Data from the App to the Webserver you may want to use the flag true.

```
$post = json_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data'), true);
foreach ($post as $obj) {
  echo  $obj["yourobj"];
}
```

If you have problems parsing the data from the webserver to the app, force it to be an object by using

```
json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

if you want to parse an array use

```
json_encode(array("data", $yourdata));
```

Please explain what you want and the error you get for a proper solution matching your case.